# SQL to select rows where all associations have not null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `workflows` and `tasks`. Tasks belong to a workflow.

I want to select all workflows where **all** the tasks associated with them are complete.

For example:

Workflow 1

- Task A - `completed_at = 2020-01-01`
- Task B - `completed_at = null`

Workflow 2

- Task C - `completed_at = 2020-01-01`
- Task D - `completed_at = 2020-01-01`

Workflow 3

- Task E - `completed_at = 2020-01-01`
- Task F - `completed_at = 2020-01-01`

I want to run a query that only selects workflow 2 and 3 since their tasks are complete and have no incomplete tasks.

Comment: Hint: `count(*)` counts all rows, `count(col)` counts rows with non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try "not in subquery" as follows:

```sql
select * 
from workflows
where workflow_id not in (select workflow_id 
                            from tasks 
                           where completed_at is null)
```